# Is the cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$ regular, working in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Is the cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$ [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_cardinal), working in ZFC?

Comment: IIRC, all you can say is that the cofinality of $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountable - but for example, there's a forcing model in which $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_{\omega_1}$ and therefore is not regular.

Comment: In ZFC it is neither provably regular nor provably singular, since both $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_{\omega_1}$ are consistent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory) : see the corollary section for a proof that $2^{\aleph_0}$ has uncountable cofinality.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily - all ZFC can prove is that the cofinality of $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountable. (That $cof(2^{\aleph_0})>\omega$ follows from [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)); that this is the only restriction provable from ZFC is due to Solovay, and a huge strengthening of this result is [due to Easton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem).) It is consistent, for example, that $$2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega_1},$$ which is of course singular.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Thanks for the comments.